# How to use Azure monitoring solution for containers?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-monitoring

I have a resource group that looks like this:

[image]

I have added the container monitoring solution to my log analytics workspace. I have enabled application logging like so for my web app:

[image]

However, I can't find any logs anywhere. When I check the logs in both my web app, container monitoring solution and log analytics workspace it doesn't show me any logs. How can I "connect" my container to the container monitoring solution to view information about my container. I have read this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/containers, but I couldn't understand from that how to actually use it in practice when I have an exisiting web app that I want to view in my monitoring solution. I guess what I'm looking for is a basic step-by-step guide to setup the whole web app-monitoring-analytics workspace solution.

Comment: s it deployed on aks?

Comment: No, just a regular web app for container